# How Can I find the medical image datasets for congenital heart defect

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, dataset, computer-vision, data-science-model

I am working on implementing the image segmentation model for diagnosing a patient with a congenital heart defect.
But I couldn't find the image datasets.
please, anyone, help me to Find the Image Datasets for a congenital heart defect?

Comment: Are you implementing a model but do not have data?

Comment: yes, Craig, I am searching for data.

Comment: Well this is a hard one. You got assigned to build a model that you do not have data for. Where will the data come from when the model is in production?